# How to setup and RPC call that accepts a u128 input?

Tags: rust, polkadot-js, u128, serialization

I cannot seem to setup a RPC call that accepts a `u128` param.

I can input the following

```
let u128Input = new BN("10")
let output = await api.rpc.template.testRpc(u128Input);
```

but get an error when the number is large

```
let u128Input = new BN("10000000000000000")
let output = await api.rpc.template.testRpc(u128Input);
```

I get the following error

```
RPC-CORE: testRpc(amount: Balance): Balance:: -32602: Invalid params: invalid type: string "0x0000000000000000002386f26fc10000", expected u128.
RpcError: -32602: Invalid params: invalid type: string "0x0000000000000000002386f26fc10000", expected u128.
```

My `runtime-api/src/lib.rs` file looks like

```rs
sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
    pub trait TemplateApi<Balance> where
        Balance: Codec + MaybeDisplay,
    {
        fn test_rpc(amount: Balance) -> Result<u64, DispatchError>;
    }
}
```

What should I change to allow `u128` inputs?

### Update

`NumberOrHex` was exactly what I needed

I updated the `rpc/runtime-api/src/lib.rs` to look like

```rs
sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
    pub trait TemplateApi<Balance> where
        Balance: Codec,
    {
        fn test_rpc(amount: Balance) -> Result<Balance, DispatchError>;
    }
}
```

I updated the `rpc/src/lib.rs` to look like

```rs
#[rpc]
pub trait TemplateApi<BlockHash, Balance>
where
    Balance: Codec + Copy + TryFrom<NumberOrHex>,
{
    #[rpc(name = "template_testRpc")]
    fn test_rpc(&self, amount: NumberOrHex, at: Option<BlockHash>) -> Result<NumberOrHex>;
}
```

Also the `impl` had to be updated and added a custom serialization and deserialization

```rs
impl<C, Block, Balance> TemplateApi<<Block as BlockT>::Hash, Balance> for Api<C, Block>
where
    Block: BlockT,
    C: Send + Sync + 'static,
    C: ProvideRuntimeApi<Block>,
    C: HeaderBackend<Block>,
    C::Api: TemplateRuntimeApi<Block, Balance>,
    Balance: Codec + Copy + TryFrom<NumberOrHex> + Into<NumberOrHex> + std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn test_rpc(
        &self,
        amount: NumberOrHex,
        at: Option<<Block as BlockT>::Hash>,
    ) -> Result<NumberOrHex> {
        let api = self.client.runtime_api();
        let at: BlockId<Block> = BlockId::hash(at.unwrap_or(self.client.info().best_hash));

        let try_into_rpc_balance = |value: Balance| {
            value.try_into().map_err(|_| RpcError {
                code: ErrorCode::InvalidParams,
                message: format!("{} doesn't fit in NumberOrHex representation", value),
                data: None,
            })
        };

        let res = api
            .test_rpc(&at, decode_hex(amount, "balance")?)
            .map_err(runtime_error_into_rpc_error)?
            .map_err(test_rpc_error)?;

        try_into_rpc_balance(res)
    }
}

...

fn decode_hex<H: std::fmt::Debug + Copy, T: TryFrom<H>>(from: H, name: &str) -> Result<T> {
    from.try_into().map_err(|_| RpcError {
        code: ErrorCode::InvalidParams,
        message: format!("{:?} does not fit into the {} type", from, name),
        data: None,
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you try converting to a byte array (`u8a`) before you send it into the RPC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the RPCs, I believe `NumberOrHex` is what you are after. Here is an example from the [contracts RPC](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/2287cd80830b081bd51bd8c313c6213d312e541e/frame/contracts/rpc/src/lib.rs#L74-L85), where both the `value` & `gas_limit` are defined as this type.

I believe it is possibly something like (untested and I'm certainly not a Rust dev...) -

```rust
use sp_rpc::number::NumberOrHex;

...

pub trait TemplateApi<Balance> where
        Balance: Codec + Copy + TryFrom<NumberOrHex>,
    {
        fn test_rpc(amount: Balance) -> Result<u64, DispatchError>;
    }
```

Comment: this was super helpful thanks Jaco!