# u128 is not supported on jsonrpc

Tags: rpc, u128

u128 is [not supported](https://github.com/paritytech/jsonrpc/issues/470) on rpc. So I am trying to use NumberOrHex

[How to setup and RPC call that accepts a u128 input?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/how-to-setup-and-rpc-call-that-accepts-a-u128-input)

Here is my code for runtime api:

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
use codec::Codec;

sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
    pub trait ShivarthuApi<U128> where
    U128: Codec {
        fn hello_world() -> U128;
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
sp-api = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.18" }
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "2.3.1" }
```

It gives error:

```
the trait bound `U128: sp_api_hidden_includes_DECL_RUNTIME_APIS::sp_api::parity_scale_codec::WrapperTypeDecode` is not satisfied

the trait `sp_api_hidden_includes_DECL_RUNTIME_APIS::sp_api::parity_scale_codec::WrapperTypeDecode` is not implemented for `U128`

note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `sp_api_hidden_includes_DECL_RUNTIME_APIS::sp_api::Decode` for `U128`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had this same issue with our Polymesh chain.  To fix it you need to enable the `arbitrary_precision` feature on `serde_json` and `jsonrpc-core` crates.

Check your `Cargo.toml` files (there might be more than one) for those two crates and make sure the feature is enabled like this:

```
jsonrpc-core = { version = "15.0", features = ["arbitrary_precision"] }
serde_json = { version = "1.0", features = ["arbitrary_precision"] }
```

You can see the commit where we fixed it here:
https://github.com/PolymathNetwork/Polymesh/commit/5ee2801fcf9f34b7efa78e909782bf77154c0b0f

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I thought only serde_json has "arbitrary_precision", but I had only jsonrpc-core as dependancy.